# Php preg_match using URL as regex

Tags: php, regex

i have an array of urls

```
[
  'http://www.example.com/eng-gb/products/test-1',
  'http://www.example.com/eng-gb/products/test-3',
  'http://www.example.com/eng-gb/about-us',
]
```

I need to write a regex for filter only the ones end with:

```
http://www.example.com/eng-gb/products/(.*)
```

in this case i need to exclude 'about-us'.

I need also use `'http://www.example.com/eng-gb/products/(.*)'` as regex.

The best way for archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_grep()` provides a shorter line of code, but because the substring to be matched doesn't appear to have any variable characters in it, best practice would indicate `strpos()` is better suited.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0f4f5b3e0c716240fd9ab7d2bc7d74d49a0428b8))

```
$urls=[
  'http://www.example.com/eng-gb/products/test-1',
  'http://www.example.com/eng-gb/badproducts/test-2',
  'http://www.example.com/eng-gb/products/test-3',
  'http://www.example.com/eng-gb/badproducts/products/test-4',
  'http://www.example.com/products/test-5',
  'http://www.example.com/eng-gb/about-us',
];

var_export(preg_grep('~^http://www.example\.com/eng-gb/products/[^/]*$~',$urls));
echo "\n\n";
var_export(array_filter($urls,function($v){return strpos($v,'http://www.example.com/eng-gb/products/')===0;}));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'http://www.example.com/eng-gb/products/test-1',
  2 => 'http://www.example.com/eng-gb/products/test-3',
)

array (
  0 => 'http://www.example.com/eng-gb/products/test-1',
  2 => 'http://www.example.com/eng-gb/products/test-3',
)
```

Some notes:

Using `preg_grep()`:

- Use a non-slash pattern delimiter so that you don't have to escape all of the slashes inside the pattern.
- Escape the dot at `.com`.
- Write the full domain and directory path with start and end anchors for tightest validation.
- Use a negated character class near the end of the pattern to ensure that no additional directories are added (unless of course you wish to include all subdirectories).
- My pattern will match a url that ends with `/products/` but not `/products`.  This is in accordance with the details in your question.

Using `strpos()`:

- Checking for `strpos()===0` means that the substring must be found at the start of the string.
- This will allow any trailing characters at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) cause you have array of urls
and this will return array of url that match your condition

`$matches = preg_grep('/products\/.*$/', $urls);`

and also you can use [validate filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) in php to validate urls

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape the forward slashes and periods to get `http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/eng-gb\/products\/(.*)`. After that, you could just place the URL in directly.

Alternatively (better) would be to search for `\/eng-gb\/products\/(.*)`.

Example:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/\/eng-gb\/products\/(.*)/', $your_url, $matches);
$product = $matches[1];
```